# How to query for multiple items in java script?

Tags: javascript, rally

I am developing charts and dashboard in Rally.  So, I need to query information for both iteration 1 and iteration2.

```
queryConfig[2] = {
        type: 'release',
        key: 'release',
        fetch: 'ReleaseStartDate,ReleaseDate',
        query: rally.sdk.util.Query.or([
                       'Name = "IR 1"', 
                       'Name = "IR 2"'
                   ])
    };
```

Above you will find a snapshot of how I am querying for iteration 1 and 2 (that is IR 1 and IR 2).  This approach does not seem to work.  Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: -1. You are asking us to write your code.

Comment: I am asking what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I disagree the user is asking us how he can make a query work that they do not understand. Above shows a failed attempt that they tried

Comment: @user1133324. Format your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it should work. Is there a space at the end of your iteration name? Try replacing the = with a contains. Also try throwing a wider new with your search and see if that gives you anything.

Here is an example

```
queryConfig[2] = {
    type: 'release',
    key: 'release',
    fetch: 'ReleaseStartDate,ReleaseDate',
    query: rally.sdk.util.Query.or([
                   'Name = "1"', 
                   'Name = "2"'
               ])
};
```

Also if you want to debug your query you can use this [App](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/WsapiReference). The query generated by util will be shown in your console and that App can help you visualize it.

```
console.log(rally.sdk.util.Query.or([
                   'Name = "1"', 
                   'Name = "2"'
               ]).toString());
```